# Telling a static dll from a dynamic dll from Code

Tags: c++, dll

I am currently generating a dll file in c++ VS2010 .I had two questions I wanted to know if I am currently generating a static dll or a dynamic dll ? In my code I have a .def file and all my exported functions are numbered in that def file. Also my functions are being exported using __declspec(dllexport).

Comment: Dude. There's no such thing as a static dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you generate a DLL you will get a *Dynamic* Link Library. So independent on the method you generate it, it is dynamically loaded.

But there is a difference how you access the functions from your cosuming application.

When you use the import library (yourDllName.LIB) the DLL will be loaded when your application is loaded. This gives a similar look&feel as if you would use a static library.

You can also use LoadLibrary and GetProcAddress to get a pointer to the functions. Then you can call your functions using these pointers to the DLL entrypoints.

If you choose the module export file (.DEF) ot the __declspec(dllexport) method to put the function to the export table doesn't care. I recommend using one method to avoid confusion.

Comment: the *.def file does care. without the def file there is name decoration. with the def file you can ensure the undecorated naming independently of calling convention or debug/release

Answer (score -1):

In your C++ code, you can check for symbol _DLL being defined.

```
#ifdef _DLL
```

I do not think you need to assign ordinal numbers to function when building a static library.

Comment: Please leave a comment for the -1.  I don't bite, honest.